# How to merge duplicate values into single record in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I have to merge the duplicate values into single record. For example

```
CNTCT_CD  EMP_ID 
1          2     
2          3
3          2
5          2
4          3
```

And I want it in this format.

```
CNTCT_CD   EMP_ID
1,3,5       2
2,4         3
```

How can I do it and which collection is better to use here. I am new to this forum and java as well

Comment: What do you mean by a single record? Are you talking a database record or you custom record data structure? In what format do you have the data?

Comment: Use `HashMap<EMP_ID,ArrayList<CNTCT_CD>>` ?

Comment: I have a list in that like List<ABC> abc=new ArrayList<ABC>(); and all this data is in that list. So i want to merge the duplicate ones into single.

Comment: @Billiska, or guava `ArrayListMultimap` :)

Comment: Did you studied java [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)? I strongly recommend to learn them if you're not familiar with them. As @Billiska mentioned map with list as value will be fine in your case.

Comment: @user1489531: Than it would be useful if you posted the whole code, including what `ABC` is.

Comment: What's ABC? Do you have EMP_ID and CNTCT_CD both in ABC? Or you have two such separate lists? How do you relate the two together in your lists?

Answer (score 2):

Use `HashMap<Integer, StringBuilder>`

key = EMP_ID (Integer; String if it is alphanumeric)

value = comma separated CNTCT_CD values

```
HashMap<Integer, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<Integer, StringBuilder>();

//Assuming that you populate List<Integer> idList yourself

for (Integer id : idList)
{
   StringBuilder builder = null;
   if (map.containsKey(id))
   {
       builder = map.get(id);
       builder.append(",");
   }
   else
   {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   }

   builder.append("<respective-value>");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure OP needs to get value as `String` and not list of integers?

Comment: OP needs to be list of string

Comment: First of all how I am going to Identify duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Can also use `HashMap<String, Set<String>>`

key = String `EMP_ID`

value = Set of String(`CNTCT_CDs`)

Code:

Just create a class to represent a record like

```
CNTCT_CD  EMP_ID
```

1          2

```
public class Record {

    private String empId;
    private String cntctId;

//setters and getters
//constructors
}
```

Process all records by creating a list of records as follows:
Set is used to eliminate duplicate cntct ids

```
    List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
    records.add(new Record("1", "2"));
    records.add(new Record("2", "3"));
    records.add(new Record("3", "2"));
    records.add(new Record("5", "2"));
    records.add(new Record("4", "3"));

    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    //Storing records as per your desired format
    for (Record record : records) {
        //if its a new key, add key and value(in a Set)
        if (!map.keySet().contains(record.getEmpId())) {
            Set<String> cntctIds = new HashSet<String>();
            cntctIds.add(record.getCntctId());
            map.put(record.getEmpId(), cntctIds);
        //key already added, just add the value to the added Set
        } else {
            map.get(record.getEmpId()).add(record.getCntctId());
        }
    }
```

Hey you can use `Integer` in place of `String` above.
Thats it!

Comment: how to identify duplicates?

Comment: there will be no duplicate as Set contains only unique collection of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean wich data structure to use, I guess the best option is an Hash Map where the EMP_ID is the key. When you try to insert an element and already exists one with that key, append it to the existing one

EDIT
Assuming your objects are ABC, it can look like this, depends in how you want to group the duplicates:

```
HashMap<String, Group of ABC> map = new HashMap<String, Group of ABC>();

void insert (ABC item){
    <Group of ABC> existing = map.get(item.EMP_ID);
    if (existing == null){
         G = new <Group of ABC>()
         map.put(ABC.EMP_ID, G);
    } else {
        existing.append(ABC); //Here comes to you how to merge 2 items of this kind (append strings, use a list...)
        map.put(item.EMP_ID, existing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from you question what you have but I'll try to guess.
Suppose that we have 2 arrays: `cnctd_cd` and `emp_id`:

```
 int[] cntct_cd = {1, 2, 3, 5, 4};
 int[] emp_id = {2, 3, 2, 2, 3};
```

You need to combine all cntct_cd by emp_id, so we can find for an employee all his cntct_cd (whatever it means). I'd suggest following algoritm:

```
 //define map that will contain list of cntct_cd by emp_id
 Map<Integer, List<Integer>> grouped = ...;
 // for each item in arrays do following:
     // check if grouped contains current emp_id
     // if not, put new empty list for current emp_id to grouped map.

     // get list from grouped by emp_id and add current cntct_cd to this list

 // At the end you'll get map of all cntct_cd combined by emp_id
```

It's kinda pseudocode :)